# Seamless animation loop

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate 2 character having hot time(nfsw). My problem is whatever I tried I cant make my animation loop seamlessly. I have tried to make my frames 1 less frame. For example my animation 1-24 I made it 1-23(end frame) but it didint worked. Also I have tried to choose all key frames and use linear or cycle modifers but none of them working. What Im doing wrong? Pls dont fix my problem teach me what is wrong and what should I do.

Comment: Also I can share blend file but I dont know how

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141712/how-to-create-a-seamless-animation-loop-in-blender?rq=1

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7912/looping-walk-cycle-animation-snaps-back-on-repeat?rq=1

Comment: I probly checked every topic about that and I saw your links before already.

Comment: Hard to tell without blend file. The things you say you already tried should have worked in one way or another, so I can only imagine you did them somehow wrong - but there's not enough information in the question to determine what exactly is wrong.

Comment: [How to share a blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/53513/)