# Blender game character is not responding to game logic

Tags: animation, game-engine

I have made an action animation with an IK rig. The mesh has a mirror, subsurf, and armature modifier.

I began making my character walk by using a keyboard sensor connected to an and brick connected to a motion and an action brick. I set the action to my walking animation and set the start to 0 and the end to 80 on play (I wanted to test it before I looped it) but when I pressed <kbd>P</kbd> and then <kbd>W</kbd> for my walking the character moved but the animation did not play.

Here is the [.blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/?xymd4f1j154n5e3)

Answer (score 1):

The BGE can't handle the *Mirror Modifier* when you apply it and change the order of the modifiers:

[image]

Some notes:

- For performance and to avoid issues it would be better to apply the subsurf also
- 80 Frames is a bit long for this walk cycle
- Loop Stop / End should be used in the action actuators
- Related: [How should an animated character be moved while repeating a walk cycle?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/how-should-an-animated-character-be-moved-while-repeating-a-walk-cycle/3740#3740)

Result (reduced to 20 frames and adjusted movement):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The blender game engine doesn't support IK rigs. I had the same problem some time ago. Unfortunatly I ended up recreating the animation. I then used the Auto IK function to still use IK.