# character movement does not work in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine

I want my character to walk, but my character does not move, why?

Here is my [blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2395/).
Press <kbd>P</kbd> to play and you will see the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of                                 "blender game character is not responding to game logic"       http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/blender-game-character-is-not-responding-to-game-logic

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use the *Mirror Modifier* with the BGE this way. When you apply the character's *Mirror Modifier* everything will work as expected. I only added this as an answer because [Blender game character is not responding to game logic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/blender-game-character-is-not-responding-to-game-logic) has no accepted answer.

[image]

Comment: @khoiri If this answered your question could you please mark it as answered. Thanks