# What causes this deformation when switching to FK mode?

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, makehuman

I created a walk cycle where the person moves from point A to point B.

I added a circle in object mode, then I added the constraint in pose mode. But when I put in forward X up to Z I get this amazing deformation of the object!
What is the problem? It seems that the problem occurs during the switch between IK and FK modes. Until now, I could not understand these tools.

Why do I lose the motion? In fact, When I try to execute the walk cycle in FK mode using the snap buttons, I lose all motions in IK mode!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is to complex to cover on this site, try tutorials online.

Comment: stacker has an idea, stay tuned!! :) (will read that with interest)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, I think my question is so clear. We want to animate a person walking from a point A to a point B(along a straight line or a curve between A and B)

Comment: It is not unclear, but too broad.

Comment: @stacker, I edit my example.

Comment: I am sure that the deformation is caused by the switch form FK to IK. Although, I remark that when we use IK and FK in any animation, we can not after execute this animation in the FK mode, I could running it only in IK mode!!

Answer (score 4):

After you created a walk cycle as described in an earlier post: [How should an animated character be moved while repeating a walk cycle?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/how-should-an-animated-character-be-moved-while-repeating-a-walk-cycle/3740#3740)

If only takes a few keyframes where you move the legs and arms

[image]

Note that the movement has to be in place, no keyframes must be added to the root bone.

Create a curve (This example uses a bezier circle) and add a *Follow Path* constraint to the root bone.

[image]

In the NLA editor add your action holding the walk cycle and set the repeat value that it matches the length of the animation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: and thx for the link :)

Comment: @Bithur, I edited my example